# Why are my cache levels speed so low in Memtest86?

Tags: cpu, cache, memtest86+

So my HDD recently failed and I'm testing the other devices in my laptop to see if its's worth it to replace the drive or if its better to buy a new PC (it's a bit old, 2012).

This was my first time testing RAM memory and I checked some tutorials on what to expect from a memtest86 test.

The test was fine, but I noticed the cache levels' speed shown in my PC is way slower than the ones I saw in every image or video and I'm wondering if that's normal or my CPU is failing as well.

I have an Intel Core i7-2670QM 2.20 GHz.

CLK: 2195 MHz (X64 Mode)

L1 Cache: 32K 6131 MB/s

L2 Cache: 256K 4932 MB/s

L3 Cache: 6144K 4237 MB/s

Memory: 8087M 3830 MB/s

[image: Memtest86+ Screenshot]

Thanks!